# Why do I need to add 96 bytes when Netty creates an Entry? Does 96 bytes have any special meaning?

Tags: netty

static Entry newInstance(Object msg, int size, long total, ChannelPromise promise) {

```
        **entry.pendingSize = size + CHANNEL_OUTBOUND_BUFFER_ENTRY_OVERHEAD;**

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the amount of memory the java object will need in the heap. We use this amount to update the `writability` of the `Channel` and so may mark the `Channel` as writable or not writable.

Comment: When I use jvm pointer compression, the size of Entry is 64. Can I change the default size of Entry according to this condition?

Comment: sure you can use `-Dio.netty.transport.outboundBufferEntrySizeOverhead=64`